# Type mismatch while sorting through excel file

Tags: vbscript

I am getting this error:

> Type mismatch: 'objExcel.Cells(...).Value'

while running this program:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("myFile.xlsx")

strMach = "string1,string2,string3"
arrMach = Split(strMach, ",")

for j = 0 to Ubound(arrMach) 
  remove(arrMach(j))
Next

Function remove(strValue)
  i = 1
  removeCounter = 0

  Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
    If objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value = strValue Then
      Set objRange = objExcel.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow
      objRange.Delete
      i = i - 1
      removeCounter = removeCounter + 1
    End If

    i = i + 1
  Loop

  wscript.echo strValue & " - REMOVED!"
  wscript.echo "Removed " & removeCounter & " results."
End Function
```

The program is used to search a string from all the existing rows, and if it is found, the whole row is deleted.

The error seems to come from the line:

```
Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
```

I've tried testing this on an excel file with around 50 rows and it works fine. But once I use it on an excel file with around 25,000 rows, I always get the error. Can anyone help? Does the size of the file affect my code during runtime?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I have tried this on a 50,000+ row excel sheet for testing and it worked fine. However, the same error still appears whenever I use it on an actual file. Are there any special characters/values which I should be aware of which cannot be properly handled by the code above? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to get an error like this when the cell you check contains an error, e.g. because a reference went missing due to a deleted row.

Add some debugging code to identify the culprit:

```
On Error Resume Next
Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
  If Err Then Exit Do
  If objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value = strValue Then
    Set objRange = objExcel.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow
    objRange.Delete
    i = i - 1
    removeCounter = removeCounter + 1
  End If

  i = i + 1
Loop

If Err Then
  WScript.Echo "Error " & Err.Number & " in row "& i & ": " & Err.Description
  WScript.Echo "Value is: " & objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value
End If
On Error Goto 0
```